# How to add an html element at each two items with foreach or SPL?

Tags: php, foreach, spl

How can I interrupt a loop and adding an html element at each **two** iterations? Can a simple `foreach` do that or something in `SPL`?

```
<?php foreach($items as $index=>$item): ?>
     <li>$item->title</li>
     <?php if($index + 1 = 2):?>
     <div class="divider"></div>
     <?php endif;?> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

html result,

```
<li>title 1</li>
<li>title 2</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 3</li>
<li>title 4</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 5</li>
<li>title 6</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<li>title 1</li>
<li>title 2</li>
<li>title 3</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 4</li>
<li>title 5</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 6</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this result :

```
<li>title 1</li>
<li>title 2</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 3</li>
<li>title 4</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 5</li>
<li>title 6</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

Do this with modulus 2 :

```
<?php 
foreach($items as $index=>$item) {
  if ($îndex % 2 = 0) {
?>
<?php // <!-- ADD HTML HERE !> ?>
<li>$item->title</li>
<?php
  } else {
?>
<li>$item->title</li>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

For this result :

```
<li>title 1</li>
<li>title 2</li>
<li>title 3</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 4</li>
<li>title 5</li>
<div class="divider"></div>
<li>title 6</li>
```

Do this with skipping the first index and modulus 2 :

```
<?php 
foreach($items as $index=>$item) {
  if ($îndex != 0 && $îndex % 2 = 0) {
?>
<?php // <!-- ADD HTML HERE !> ?>
<li>$item->title</li>
<?php
  } else {
?>
<li>$item->title</li>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Manu for the answer. but it produces the result in my edit above... may I ask - what does this mean by `$index%2`?

Comment: I added 1 to the condition to get the right result I want `($index+1)%2 == 0`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php : do not need to add 1 to `$index`. You need to get information about modulus operator `%`. Do you know this operator ? I cannot explain more here it could be too long and not appropriate in this forum.

Comment: `$index` start at `0` or `1` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php foreach($items as $index=>$item){ ?> 

<li>$item->title</li>

if ($index != 0 && $index%2 == 0){?><div class="divider"></div><?php} 

}?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but it produces the result in my edit above... what does this mean `$index%2`?

Comment: I added 1 to the condition to get the right result I want `($index+1)%2 == 0`